# Check Array output

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm struggling to understand the output of this program which is 5. Doesn't the array add one to count only if the array next to it is equal.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int arr[12] = {1,3,5,0,7,2,0,4,4,0,8,8};
   int count = 0;
   for(int i=0;i<11;i++) {
      if(arr[i] = arr[i+1] )
         count++;
      else
         count--;
    }
    cout << count << endl; 
}
```

Comment: You *do* know there's a difference between assignment (`=`) and comparison for equality (`==`)?

Answer (score 0):

Change `if(arr[i] = arr[i+1])`

to

```
if(arr[i] == arr[i+1])
```

Your output should no longer be 5. Also, try reviewing your code thoroughly in the future. You may spend a lot of time debugging, but it will make you a better programmer.